# Code to filter out problematic 0 and NA entries

Tags: r, rstudio

Total newbie here, I totally apologize if/when at any point I sound like a complete idiot.

I am working in RStudio. I have imported a data file from excel. It has several columns with health information such as age, blood pressure, BMI, and a couple others. I need to remove the entries with 0s in a couple of the columns (you can't have 0 BMI or blood pressure) I also need to remove all of the entries with NAs.

I am stuck on what to do. I have tried the na.omit function, but afterwords I try doing things like mean() median() and it gives me the message "argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA" which makes no sense. I thought the NAs were supposed to be removed.

Please help. I need help cleaning this data.

Comment: Please see this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Here is a great resource for starting with R . http://r4ds.had.co.nz/index.html. As per the guidelines for posting, please include sample code of how far you were able to get.

Comment: In case a row has BMI == 0 but blood_pressure != 0 ( or viceversa), or BMI == NA but blood_pressure != NA (or viceversa) are you going to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's not good to remove the NA's because it may be NA for one column, but not the other, so you may exclude the wrong thing.

With the stats library, you can use the complete.cases(df) to remove all NA.

To change 0's to NA, you can do:

```
df[ df == 0] <- NA
```

Also if you want to ignore NA's while doing calculations you can do

```
median(df$col,na.rm = TRUE)
```

This will remove the NA from the calculations and you won't get NA as an output.

Answer (score 0):

A tidyverse solution might look like this. Tidyverse is a set of packages developed by the R Studio team.

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- data %>%
  filter(BMI != 0, BloodPressure != 0, col != NA)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to make sure that the columns you are interested in are `numeric` not `character` because direct import from excel files could produce unexpected column types. To do so use the function `class(data_name$column_name)`.

Character variables cannot be handled with `mean()` and `median()` so you have to convert them first to `numeric` using

```
data_name$column_name <- as.numeric(data_name$column_name)
```

After that you can replace zeros with `NA` using `ifelse` function:

```
data_name$column_name <- ifelse(data_name$column_name == 0, NA, data_name$column_name)
```

Then, you can compute the mean and median in the normal way using the argument `na.rm` to remove missing values (`NA`):

```
mean_BMI <- mean(data_name$BMI, na.rm = TRUE)
```